# Using loops in to make a dynamic array structure and then convert it to a static array

Tags: r

I would like to dynamically parameterize an array for a state-space model depending on how many states I choose.

I am doing this with a loop -

```
Q <- function(params,states) {
qmat <- matrix(0,statespace,statespace)
for (i in 1:statespace)
  qmat[i,i] <- statshockvar(params[(i-1)*5+1], params[(i-1)*5+2], 
                            params[(i-1)*5+3],states[i])          
qmat            

}
```

This function is called many times, as the point of the program is to optimize a paramter set. However, this function setup is slowing down the optimization phase very substantially because this function and a bunch of others like it keep getting called, and they keep redefining the arrays.

How can I define the arrays I need once, **dynamically**, with the relevant parameters as above, and then be able to call the matrix function with a new set of parameters for optimization?

Thanks!

Edit -

`statespace` is just an integer describing the number of states to use in the model, say 3/

```
statshockvar <- function(meanrev,longrun,sigma,sstate) {

longrun*sigma^2/(2*meanrev)*(1-exp(-longrun))^2+sigma^2/longrun*(exp(-longrun) - 
  exp(-2*longrun))*sstate

}
```

`statshockvar` - in this particular example is the discretized variance of a CIR model for the term structure

Edit 2 -

params looks like this - please note these are just arbitrary number

```
params = c(
0.3275,
0.07,
0.197,
0,
0.05,

0.01,
0.2,
0.3,
0,
0.05,

0.01,
0.1,
0.3,
0,
0.05)
```

states would be something like this -

```
states = c(0.07,0.07,0.07)
```

again these states are arbitrary.

Comment: This function will be called many times say 1500 * number of times taken to optimise. This is a major bottleneck to keep reassigning the structure of the matrix for each call. So I want this to run once, and then only update the parameter values which will result in a new set of values within the predefined matrix structure... `

Comment: It's not a good idea to have your function grab data (`statespace`) from the global environment.  You should pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
Q <- function(params, states) {
  diag(mapply(function(y, z) statshockvar(y[1], y[2], y[3], z), 
              lapply(seq(statespace), function(x) params[(x-1)*5 + 1:3]), 
              states))
}
```

Test with the example parameters:

```
Q(params, states)

            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 0.002465305 0.00000000 0.000000000
[2,] 0.000000000 0.03424762 0.000000000
[3,] 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.009499883
```

Comment: Sven, will this work if states is determined by the statespace variable mentioned above? ie, this is what determines length of the states vector...

Comment: @user2006864 The variable `statespace` is part of the solution: `lapply(seq(statespace)...`.

Comment: I am still wondering however - how do I stop r from reassigning the matrix structure every time the function q is called?

Comment: @user2006864 The function is designed to create the matrix. What do you expect the function to do?

Comment: This function will be called many times say 1500 * number of times taken to optimise. This is a major bottleneck to keep reassigning the structure of the matrix for each call. So I want this to run once, and then only update the parameter values which will result in a new set of values within the predefined matrix structure...

Comment: @user2006864 I have no idea of your optimization process. Your original function creates matrix but does not change values in an existing matrix. You should pose another question on this topic if you want to further improve your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the for loop,

```
for (i in 1:statespace)
  qmat[i,i] <- statshockvar(params[(i-1)*5+1], params[(i-1)*5+2], 
                            params[(i-1)*5+3],states[i])
```

If `statshockvar` is vectorized, you can simply write

```
diag(qmat) <- statshockvar(params[((1:statespace)-1)*5+1], params[((1:statespace)-1)*5+2], params[((1:statespace)-1)*5+3], states[1:statespace])
```

If it's not,  see `?Vectorize` to make it so